# Trouble figuring out how to make a proper request based on another API

Tags: c#, json

I'm having some trouble creating a request.

There is an another API that have a request pattern like this:

```
{
  "someNumber":"111222333",
   "theList":{
     "0":"1233",
     "1":"2333"          
   },
  "something":"thisThing"
}
```

My trouble is with `theList`. How can I simulate those indexes on the request at my API? What I did was the following:

```
public class Item
{
    [JsonProperty("someNumber")]
    public long Number{ get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("theList")]
    public List<string> NumberList{ get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("something")]
    public string Something{ get; set; }
}
```

But this is obviously not correct, what is the best way to simulate what was done in the other API?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The json structure for `theList` can be deserialized into a `Dictionary<string,string>`:

```
public class Item
{
    [JsonProperty("someNumber")]
    public long Number{ get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("theList")]
    public Dictionary<string, string> NumberList{ get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("something")]
    public string Something{ get; set; }
}
```

[Demo](https://dotnetfiddle.net/VNNHIF)

---

If the keys and values in `theList` are always numbers, and since you're using `Netwontoft.Json`, you could also deserialize straight into `Dictionary<int, int>`, `Dictionary<int, long>`, `Dictionary<string, long>`, etc. However, this won't work in `System.Text.Json`.